# Passing values to g_timeout_add_seconds() not working?

Tags: c, glib

I'm trying to pass a value into a function used in g_timeout_add_seconds(), but it's not working as expected.  It works when I pass a value into the function normally.  Am I using g_timeout_add_seconds() incorrectly?

```
typedef struct { int x, y; } xy_t;

void fn_init(void)
{
  xy_t  xy;
  int    z;

  xy.x =  12;
  xy.y =  23;
  z    = 123;
  pass_thru_test1(&xy);
  pass_thru_test2(&xy);
  pass_thru_test3(&z);

  z = 234;
  g_timeout_add_seconds(1, pass_thru_test3, &z);
}

gboolean pass_thru_test1(xy_t *data)
{
  xy_t *point = (xy_t *)data;
  printf("Pass Thru Test 1: x:%d, y:%d\n", point->x, point->y);
  return TRUE;
}

gboolean pass_thru_test2(gpointer data)
{
  xy_t *p = (xy_t *)data;
  printf("Pass Thru Test 2: x:%d, y:%d\n", p->x, p->y);
  return TRUE;
}

gboolean pass_thru_test3(gpointer data)
{
  int *point = (int *)data;
  printf("Pass Thru Test 3: %d\n", *p);
  return TRUE;
}
```

the results are:

```
Pass Thru Test 1: x:12, y:23
Pass Thru Test 2: x:12, y:23
Pass Thru Test 3: 123
Pass Thru Test 3: 724126128
Pass Thru Test 3: 724126128
Pass Thru Test 3: 724126128
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are sending a pointer to a local variable as the data parameter.

```
void fn_init(void)
{
  xy_t  xy;
  int    z; /* this varible is local */

  xy.x =  12;
  xy.y =  23;
  z    = 123;
  pass_thru_test1(&xy);
  pass_thru_test2(&xy);
  pass_thru_test3(&z);

  z = 234;
  g_timeout_add_seconds(1, pass_thru_test3, &z);
}
```

the variable lives in the stack frame of `fn_init()` and when you access it inside the `pass_through*` functions, it was already deallocated because `fn_init()` returns right after calling `g_timeout_add_secons()`.

And don't forget to `free(z)` when you are done working with it.

```
gboolean pass_thru_test3(gpointer data)
{
  int *point;
  point = (int *)data;
  if (point == NULL)
      return FALSE;
  printf("Pass Thru Test 3: %d\n", *point);
  free(data);
  return TRUE;
}
```

There are two possible solutions, depending on what your function is really going to do, use `malloc()`

```
void fn_init(void)
{
  xy_t  xy;
  int   *z;

  xy.x =  12;
  xy.y =  23;

  z = malloc(sizeof(*z));
  if (z == NULL)
     return;
  *z = 123;

  pass_thru_test1(&xy);
  pass_thru_test2(&xy);
  pass_thru_test3(z);

  *z = 234;
  g_timeout_add_seconds(1, pass_thru_test3, z);
}
```

You can also make `z` static, but then it will be the same `z` every time you call `fn_init()` and modifications are preserved accross function calls.

Comment: It's just an int, so GPOINTER_TO_INT and GINT_TO_POINTER is also an option.